# problem with infinite loop in python list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Am working through Sweigart's "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python." He provides the following example of a simple list program. I am following his coding exactly but the program produces an infinite loop. What am I missing?

tried searching for others who had the same result when working with this example. Could not find anything.

```
catNames=[]
while True:
     print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) +1) + ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
     name=input()
     if name == '':
          break
     catNames = catNames + [name]
print('The cat names are:')
for name in CatNames:
     print('    ' + name)
```

Result should be:

```
The cat names are:
   tommy
   spot
   paws
   etc.
```

Instead, I get an infinite loop of the first print command.

Comment: `CatNames` is not defined, but even after fixing it I can't reproduce the issue. Please double-check your code. See [mre] for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo here:

```
for name in CatNames:
     print('    ' + name)
```

CatNames should be catNames (lowercase c in catNames) then it works. Also, the loop will keep taking names until you stop entering names. Just hit enter without entering a name and the loop will break and the output will be displayed.